# Highlight rows in quick edit view

Tags: web-part

In the quick edit view, I would like some rows to be highlighted based on values from two columns. One of the columns is a choice column and the other is a text column.
I was able to highlight using js and one column.How can I check values in 2 columns for highlighting the rows. Would appreciate any help!thanks.
Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $Text = $("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('test2')");       
        $Text.css("background-color", "#EAC117");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Plenty alternative solutions explained here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a32871%20icc

Basic concept is to make the row color itself, instead of using bloated jQuery and ductaping caode on the page after it already loaded.

```
 =IF(  AND ( [TextField]="text2" , [ChoiceField] = "choice1" )
     ,"<IMG src="blank.gif" onload="""

       Execute JavaScript to color 'this' TR row

     ,"<!--Non matching fields-->"

 )
```

Note: same can be done with CSR - Client Side Rendering, also no jQuery required